# How do I import images into processing with a transparent background?

Tags: java, processing

So I have png image files in my processing data folder that have the checkered background, meaning they should support transparency. However, when the images load, they still include that checkered background and I'm wondering how to make the background fully transparent.

Using the tint() method makes the entire image tint which is not what I want.
Heres what I have:

```
public class Enemy
{
    PImage en1;
    float w, h; 
    float center_x, center_y;
    float change_x, change_y; 
  
 
public Enemy(String filename, float scale,float x, float y)
{
    en1 = loadImage(filename);
    w = en1.width*scale;
    h = en1.height*scale;
    center_x = x;
    center_y = y;
    change_x = 0;
    change_y = 0;
        
}
  
public Enemy(String filename, float scale)
{
    this(filename,scale,0,0); 
   
}
  
public void display()
{
    if(center_x < 0 ) {center_x = 0;}
    if(center_x > width) {center_x = 0;}
    if(center_y < 0 ) {center_y = 0;}
    if(center_y > height) {center_y = 0;}
    
    image(en1, center_x, center_y, w, h);
}

}

// global variables
final static float MOVE_SPEED = 5;
Sprite p;
Enemy e;

PImage map;
int y;

void etup()
{
    size(800,600);
  
  
    map = loadImage("map.png");
    map.resize(800,600);
  
    p = new Sprite("Sprite.png", 0.15, 0, 300);
    p.change_x = 0;
    p.change_y = 0;
  
    e = new Enemy("enemy.jpg", 0.15, 300, 300);
    e.change_x = 0;
    e.change_y = 0;
  
}

void draw()
{
  
    background(map);
  
    stroke(226, 204, 0);
    line(0, y, width, y);
    
    y++;
    if( y > height)
    {
        y = 0;
    }
  
    p.display();
    p.update();
    
e.display();
  
}


void keyPressed()
{
  if(keyCode == RIGHT)
  {
     p.change_x = MOVE_SPEED; 
  }
  else if(keyCode == LEFT)
  {
     p.change_x = -MOVE_SPEED; 
  }
  else if(keyCode == UP)
  {
     p.change_y = -MOVE_SPEED; 
  }

}

void keyReleased()
{
  if(keyCode == RIGHT)
  {
     p.change_x = 0; 
  }
  else if(keyCode == LEFT)
  {
     p.change_x = 0; 
  }
  else if(keyCode == UP)
  {
     p.change_y = 0; 
  }
  
}
```

Comment: You should upload these png images. It would be to double check if the checkerboard is actually an opaque background. (some image viewers and editors display transparent background as a checkerboard, but not all. if all editors/viewers show checkerboard or using a color picker and checking if the alpha value is > 0 that would point to an opaque background)